# Ruby to read csv files with double quotes

Tags: ruby, csv

CSV file, I am trying to read

```
"Customer","ID","Host name","Created","Status","OS","OS Version","RAM"
"XXX","1234","abcd","2021-12-10 12:43:09","Linux Server","RedHat RHEL82gen2","2,048"
```

This csv file has `"..."` for every column and the RAM column has its values with `,`
I am not getting to read this csv, this has double quotes and also its column has a comma(,) in its value.

I have tried using `quote_char: '"'`

Comment: can you post snippet / example code on how you read it? and also what library do you use? standard CSV library from Ruby allows the column separator to be configured

Answer (score 3):

With `"` being the default quote character and `,` being the default field separator [`CSV.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#parse-method) can read your data perfectly fine the way it is:

```
require 'csv'

data = <<-EOD
"Customer","ID","Host name","Created","Status","OS","OS Version","RAM"
"XXX","1234","abcd","2021-12-10 12:43:09","Linux Server","RedHat RHEL82gen2","2,048"
EOD

CSV.parse(data)
#=> [
#     ["Customer", "ID", "Host name", "Created", "Status", "OS", "OS Version", "RAM"],
#     ["XXX", "1234", "abcd", "2021-12-10 12:43:09", "Linux Server", "RedHat RHEL82gen2", "2,048"]
#   ]
```

Note that the last value is `"2,048"` – the comma was parsed correctly.

Comment: thanks. While it gives me the output, I do not want the "" to be there. Expect the results to be 
Customer
xxx
ID
1234
Host name
abcd
Created
2021-12-10 12:43:09 
OS
Linux Server
OS Version
 RedHat RHEL82gen2
RAM
2,048

Comment: @Shruthi The quotes are there because it is a Ruby string, if you `puts` the value you won't see the quotes.